# What can cause unreported crashes for an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an app that I occasionally receive support emails for that say the app crashed on them and won't open up anymore.  It shows 'Default.png' then exits.  Even when the app is deleted and reinstalled.

-I get no crash reports or memory issues (as reported by itunes connect using reports from a significant sample size >20k downloads)

-I've confirmed it's not limited to a specific model and not caused by jailbroken devices.

-The app doesn't have external dependencies, so why would reinstalling it not fix the problem?

What kind of problems could cause the crashing to go unreported and be persistent?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `uncaught exception handler`, depending on what you have in there, you will not get reports written out the same way, or at all, as if you did not have a handler. This will make iTunes think there is not any crash reports at all.  `Uncaught exception handlers` are commonly added as part of analytics frameworks, or third party notification tools.

While this could answer your question, a more reasonable explanation is that the crashing devices just need a device restart.

Answer (score 1):

I think every app developer with a sizable install base has struggled with an issue like this in the past.

Are you using any sort of analytics package, such as Flurry, that helps you report crashes?  We used Flurry with much greater success over Apple - Apple won't start reporting crashes to you until you have many -- and "just a few" is never enough.

Additionally, if it shows the default.png and crashes, take a hard look at your start-up code.  Are you setting something in NSUserDefaults, that if, corrupted, could cause the app to crash on startup?

Admittedly it is strange that a delete-and-reinstall doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The users aren't reporting the error reports to Apple. The crashes could come from any number of sources.

Comment: with such a big sample size surely one person who the issue affects has reporting on?  Do you have any suggestion on how I can debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could walk a user through the process of digging crash reports directly out of iTunes during the next Sync and email them directly to you.

You could try asking a user to delete the app from the device, reboot their device, then have them install the app again after a fresh reboot.